# Задержка секундомера

Tags: c#, wpf

Создал бесконечный секундомер который отсчитывает от 5 до 0, а когда значение секундомера доходит до нуля, начинает считать заново:

```
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();

    DateTime stopwatch = new DateTime(0001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(0001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 5);
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (date1.CompareTo(stopwatch) != 0)
        {
            date1 = date1.AddTicks(-10000000);
            Secundomer = date1.ToString("mm:ss");
        }
        else
        {
            date1 = date1.AddTicks(60000000);
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что после отсчета до нуля секундомер "думает" пару секунд и только после этого начинает отсчет заново. Как убрать эту задержку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он не "думает пару секунд", он продолжает работать как раньше, просто вы одну итерацию не обновляете значение на экране, поэтому вам так кажется. Вынесите вывод времени за пределы `if`:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (date1 != stopwatch)
    {
        date1 = date1.AddSeconds(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        date1 = date1.AddSeconds(5);
    }
    Secundomer = date1.ToString("mm:ss");
}
```